# Trying to generate second random number less than first random number

Tags: java, random

Ive been trying to generate a second random number less than my first random number in every scenario, but the code keeps breaking or sometimes returning null

```
     
    Random randN = new Random();
    
     int firstNumbereasy; //declaring variables  for easy mode
         int secondNumbereasy;
    
    firstNumbereasy = randN.nextInt(11); // 
    secondNumbereasy= randN.nextInt(firstNumbereasy-1);
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to generate a random number lower than the previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by running the following:

```
firstNumbereasy = randN.nextInt(MAX_RANDOM_NUM_NUMBER) + 2;
secondNumbereasy= randN.nextInt(firstNumbereasy - 1);
```

Note that the 1st number can never by 0 as otherwise you might get an exception while trying to generate the 2nd number, and that's why you always add 1 to the result...

Comment: yup just noticed it failed,  any solution

Comment: Well, practically speaking it means that you need to add 2 instead of 1 to the 1st line

Comment: just realised this , thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [Random.nextInt(bound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) docs.

To cite:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
> (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

And

> bound - the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive.

Parameter `bound` must be strictly greater than 0. If your first `nextInt()` call generaters `0` or `1`, the next bound parameter will be invalid value (0 or -1) and this results in exception.